# Update already existing data in database

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the "update ()" to update existing data in the data base of the "ModelC".

---

**Models:**

```
from django.db import models

class ModelA(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

     def __str__(self):
         return '%s' %(self.id)

class ModelB(models.Model):
     observation = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     status = models.BooleanField()
     relation = OneToOneField(ModelA)

     def __str__(self):
         return '%s' %(self.relation) 

class ModelC(models.Model):
     relationA = models.ForeignKey('ModelA', null=True, blank=True)
     date_relationA = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
     user_relationA = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
     relationB = models.ForeignKey('ModelB', null=True, blank=True)
     date_relationB = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
     user_relationB = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.id)
```

---

**Views of the ModelA:**

```
def RegModelA(request):
   form = ""
   user = None
   if request.method == "POST":
      form = ModelAForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         save = form.save()
         date = time.strftime("%d - %m - %Y")
         user = request.user.username
         create = ModelC.objects.create(relationA=save, date_relationA=date, user_relationA=user, relationB=None, date_relationB=None, user_relationB=None)
         return redirect('/')
   else:
      form = ModelAForm
   return render(request, "ModelA.html", {"form":form})
```

### **Result when registering ModelA:**

***In ModelA:***

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMJX0.png)

***In ModelC:***

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMJX0.png)

---

**Views of the ModelB:**

```
def RegModelB(request):
   form = ""
   user = None
   if request.method == "POST":
      form = ModelBForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         save = form.save()
         date = time.strftime("%d - %m - %Y")
         user = request.user.username
         update = ModelC.objects.filter().update(relationB=save, date_relationB=date, user_relationB=user)
         return redirect('/')
   else:
      form = ModelBForm
   return render(request, "ModelB.html", {"form":form})
```

---

What I am looking for is that when registering the data of the ModelB, the fields of the relationB in the ModelC are updated.

But I can not find how to obtain the ID of the ModelC, if the relation of the ModelB is equal to the field relationA in the ModelC.

I'm using:

- Python 3.5
- Django 1.11